# Derivative of $\frac{ax}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

It's being a long time since I have done maths, but now for image processing I am trying to find the derivative of the following function respect to $x$:
$$\frac{ax}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}$$ where $a$ is a constant.

Comment: Is $a$ a constant?

Comment: yes a is a constant

Comment: by the way, this is the Perona-Malik diffusion function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Quotient Rule, or the Product Rule and the Chain Rule. We have:
$$f(x) = \frac{ax}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}$$
So:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{df}{dx} &= \frac{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}(ax)' - ax\left(\sqrt{x^2+a^2}\right)'}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}^2}\\
&= \frac{a\sqrt{x^2+a^2} - ax\left(\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\right)}{x^2+a^2}\\
&= \frac{a\sqrt{x^2+a^2} - \frac{ax^2}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}}{x^2+a^2}\\
&= \frac{a(x^2+a^2) - ax^2}{(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}}\\
&= \frac{a^3}{(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}}.
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2):

You could use the rule for the derivative of a ration, of course:
$$\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)'=\frac{u'v-v'u}{v^2}$$
however, such examples involving radicals are usually easily handled by taking logarithm as the first step and keeping in mind the chain rule
$$\log{\left(u(x)\right)}=\frac{u'(x)}{u(x)}$$
from there on:

$$f(x)=\frac{ax}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}$$
$$\log{f(x)} = \log{a}+\log{x}-\frac{1}{2}\log{\left(x^2+a^2\right)}$$
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{x^2+a^2}$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{a}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}-\frac{ax^2}{\sqrt{\left(x^2+a^2\right)^3}}=\frac{a^3}{\sqrt{\left(x^2+a^2\right)^3}}$$

Comment: Your formula for derivative of a quotient has the wrong denominator on the right hand side. Should be $v^2$, not $u^2$.

Comment: corrected, thank you for pointing out

Answer (score 2):

To beat this further into the ground, here's a way to make the differentiation easy by doing a little up front algebra.

$$\frac{ax}{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}} \;\; = \;\; \frac{1}{\frac{1}{ax}\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}} \;\; = \;\; \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{a^2 x^2}\right)(x^2 + a^2)}}$$

$$= \;\; \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^{-2} + x^{-2}}} \;\; = \;\; \left(a^{-2} + x^{-2}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$

Now the derivative is an easy power rule computation:

$$\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(a^{-2} + x^{-2}\right)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\left(-2x^{-3}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that a is constant according to quotient rule 
$$\left(\frac{ax}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\right)'=\frac{a\sqrt{x^2+a^2}-ax\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}2x}{x^2+a^2}=\frac{a\sqrt{x^2+a^2}-ax^2\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}}{x^2+a^2}=\frac{a^3}{(x^2+a^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

Answer (score 0):

I like to use product rule when dealing with derivatives of rational functions. This way you need to remember only one rule instead of two.

$$\left(\frac{ax}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\right)' = a(x(x^2+a^2)^{-1/2})' = a(-x^2(x^2+a^2)^{-3/2}+(x^2+a^2)^{-1/2}
)$$

which can be simplified to

$$\frac{a^3}{(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose that 'a' is a constant.
Making the substitution, $$ x^{2} + a^2 = t $$ we have upon differentiating
$$  \frac{\mathrm{d} (x^{2} + a^2)}{\mathrm{d} t} = \frac{\mathrm{d} t}{\mathrm{d} t}
\\
\\
\Rightarrow 2x\frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{d} t} = 1
\\
\Rightarrow 2xdx = dt
\\
\Rightarrow xdx = dt/2
$$ 
Using the substitution in the integral, it reduces to 
$$a/2\int 1/\sqrt{t} dt
\\ = a/2 \frac{t^{(-1/2)+1}}{(-1/2)+1}
\\ = a/2 \frac{t^{1/2}}{1/2}
\\ = at^{1/2}
$$
Using the value of t 
$$= a\sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}}$$

Comment: You appear to have integrated when the questions asks for the derivative, I don't think this an answer to the question that was actually asked.

Comment: I read that the question asked for differentiation **after** I did the integration. And since I suck at LaTeX, I couldn't let half an hour of figuring brackets go waste.